# many of the channels are not occupied in asterisk with sangoma

Tags: asterisk

I am using 4 port and 2 port sangoma card with direct PRI (ISDN) . Only first few channels are occupying for incoming calls. Please find the below sample report for fifth PRI,

> 

```
ChannelNo Calls
125 1273
126 607
127 292
128 110
129 34
130 11
131 2
```

>

rest of the channels are not receiving the calls (132 to 155).

Is this issue is really belongs to service provider..? Please suggest..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pri card is digital card. So all channels usually(unless specialy configured) belong to one **span**(logical channel).

As you can see from your output, you have more calls on lower channel numbers. That just mean your provider not use round-robin calling but just calling first availible channel. That is ok, nothing to do with that.

That just mean you never use more then 131 concurrent channel.

Comment: Yes, I confirmed with vendor team. They are routing the calls to first available channel in the span. Thanks

Comment: That is not a problem. For digital card have no any sense do round-robin